# Method to update order state

Tags: magento

this is a question for Magento Developers.

I have and integration with Magento with a python-based framework(I'm responsible for python side).
The developer that made integration from Magento side is not with the project anymore and some sys admin is trying to handle it but is having a hard time so he can't help me.

So the question is, can I server call some method to change orders state? As I checked documentation there is no such method in Sale Order Shipment section.
We are using SOAP V1.
Magento 1.x

For example, to update product quantity I'm calling `product_stock.update` method, so maybe is there some method that I can call and update orders state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout out the `sales_order.addComment` method: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.addComment.html